# How do you sculpt the edges of a mirrored object?

Tags: sculpting, mirror

I can't figure out how to sculpt smooth the edges of a mirrored object, it always gets edgy and i end up needing to manually move vertices down the z-axis which only makes matters worse.

[image]

Or when using the "inflate" sculpting tool i end up ripping apart the object.

[image]

Or "smoothing" tool creates sharp edges at mirror edges.

[image]

Any cool links with good techniques that can be employed to sculpt/work at those mirror edges?

Comment: Are you using the Mirror modifier? In that case you need to activate the Clipping option. But you'd better don't use this modifier and simply activate the Symmetrize option

Comment: @moonboots I have the same problem no matter if _Clipping_ is enabled. Not ripping the mesh apart, that's taken care of by clipping, but smoothing edges towards the mirrored side to get rid of hard edges down the middle is almost impossible.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that but I'm not sure it's a good idea to use the Mirror modifier with sculpting

Comment: yes i used the mirror modifier. oh i thought sculptors used the mirror modifier. didn't know there was a symmetrize option. cool it works well with symmetrize! thank you @moonboots

Comment: You can symmetrize while sculpting (click on the X, Y or Z) and you can also click on the Symmetrize button whenever you want, in the symmetrize panel (down arrow on the right of XYZ)

Comment: @moonboots thanks for your help! sometimes though its weird when sculpt mode shows it smoothed out and when you go back to object mode there is a small edge. probably a bug but i can just go back in sculpt and smooth a bit again and check in object mode until its smooth again.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, maybe a bug

Comment: i meant that sometimes what you see in sculpt mode (some smoothed area) doesn't always look smoothed in object mode even with shade smooth on. but never mind it works fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the *Mirror* modifier when sculpting, instead use the X, Y or Z symmetry option (you can shift click to choose a symmetrey on 2 or 3 axis at the same time). Also, whenever you want, you can click on the *Symmetrize* button at the bottom of the symmetry panel:

[image]