# Why does my model have a crease on the chest?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I am trying to create a base model of a human body, but my theres a crease on the chest that I cannot get rid of.  I have tried adjusting the vector points, but I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: don't use mirror modifier. instead use symmeterize option when sculpting. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258144/142292

Comment: is there a way I can remove it after the fact?  The mirror modifier I actually just for the arms I didn't use it on the chest

Comment: Looks as if there may be an internal face there. Go into wireframe view with Shift-Z and delete it if there is one.